# Is it possible to enter long mode without setting up paging?

Tags: x86, x86-64, paging, osdev

I am currently trying to enter long mode, as it offers more capabilities than 16 bit real mode. Until now though, I see that in order to do so you have to set up paging which is quite confusing.

Is there a way to enter long mode, while continue using the simpler segment registers in order to address memory?

Comment: Which kind of "long mode" do you refer to?

Comment: i mean the cpu long mode . (https://wiki.osdev.org/Setting_Up_Long_Mode)

Comment: probably want to add the tag "osdev" so the right people see it. Searching [osdev] long mode, I found some hits.

Comment: ok , done that , thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Paging is *required* for long mode, you cannot enter long mode without setting up 4-level or 5-level paging first. See volume 3A section 9.8.5 of the [Intel manual](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/technical/intel-sdm.html). Specifically, the transition check is made right when enabling paging setting CR0.PG to 1, which checks if both CR4.PAE and IA32_EFER.LME are set, and if so enters IA32-e mode (Intel's name for "long mode").

> I am currently trying to enter long mode, as it offers more capabilities than 16 bit real mode.

If you are in real mode (16 bit) and need "more capabilities", the most you can do without setting up page tables is enter protected mode (32 bit), which does not require paging. The OSDev Wiki has [a simple tutorial page on the topic](https://wiki.osdev.org/Protected_Mode) with working code. The procedure is also described in the Intel manual volume 3A section 9.8.